# Difference between = and IS mysql

Tags: mysql

So I am on a site at the moment where it has an interactive MySQL Shell prompt.

I was looking up a question that a friend asked which is "why does the query fail when I use the keyword `IS` but it works when I use the `=` symbol?"

So I tested it out and sure enough it does fail.

`SELECT name, continent, population FROM world WHERE continent IS  'Asia'` failed but `SELECT name, continent, population FROM world WHERE continent = 'Asia'` works fine.

I have tried googling for an answer but no avail.

Any help would be great!

Comment: afaik the only time I use `IS` is against `NULL` or conditionals, otherwise I use `=`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[IS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is) tests against a boolean(True/False/NULL neither) where as [=](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal) tests equivalency

IS can only be used against variables that return true, false or NULL .

Comment: And also for checking for `NULL` which is neither true nor false.