# Why will mySQL not return a row with a null value when selecting != to a string

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a nullable varchar column. When selecting rows and specifying that I want rows with a value not equal to a given string, it does NOT return the rows where the value is null.

For example:

```
## if `value` is null, that row is ignored
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE value != 'some string'
```

I'd like to understand why that's happening.

Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83f0d/1

Comment: Because that is the ANSI definition of how `NULL`s behave and is how all SQL databases work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387530/difference-between-and-is-mysql/20387553#20387553

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `ANSI` SQL, `NULL` is neither equal to nor unequal to any value, including itself.

```
NULL = 'foo'
NULL != 'foo'
NULL = NULL
NULL != NULL
```

all evaluate to `NULL`.  To test for nullness you must use `is null` or `is not null` in your query.

Comment: Arguably, none of the above expressions evaluates to `FALSE`.  They evaluate to `NULL`, which is "untrue" but is equally "unfalse."

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: I'd still say it evaluates to `FALSE` because comparison must return a `BOOLEAN`. If it's not `TRUE`, it has to be `FALSE`.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr Your statement *comparison must return a `BOOLEAN`* is not true in ANSI SQL.

Comment: Well, then interestingly, it seems the standard (behind the scene) uses a `strict` comparison which has three predicates - `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NULL` (equivalent to `void`/`null`/`undefined` in various programming languages - I know it sounds silly to compare SQL to programming language but SQL is the back-end model for such languages, so it might make sense in some cases). Found [this post (SO answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9825992/1369473) which illustrates the difference with nice truth tables to help understand the simple comparison vs `IS` operator in (`ANSI`) SQL.